# Beta function integration

Tags: integration, beta-function

Calculate the integration :
$$
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{a-1}\phi\cos^{b-1}\phi\,d\phi
$$
I need help about this!
Please!

Comment: What is " (sin^a-1)fi " ?

Comment: Yes in this form is

Comment: Hint: You have to find a substitution that turns the given integral in a complete Beta.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Understand the connection between

$$\sin^{a-1}(\phi)\cos^{b-1}(\phi)$$

and

$$t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1}.$$

> Second hint: $$\cos^2(\phi)=1-\sin^2(\phi).$$